# Can't get data from firebase firestore when first run app flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a collection on firebase firestore named user, and I use the following code to get the data:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> isPhoneRegistered(
    String phone, String countryCode) async {
  int? status;
  String? error;

  try {
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    var querySnapshot = await firebaseFirestore
        .collection('users')
        .where('phone', isEqualTo: phone)
        .where('country', isEqualTo: countryCode)
        .get();
    var queryDocsSnap = querySnapshot.docs;
    if (queryDocsSnap.isNotEmpty) {
      status = 1;
    } else {
      status = 0;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    status = -1;
    error = e.toString();
    return Future.error(e);
  }

  return {'status': status, 'error': error};
}
```

it works fine when I debug, **but when I release the app and install it, the first run it always fails to get the data from the firebase firestore, but on the second run it gets the data and everything is back to normal**. This really confused me. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Would you tell what do you mean by second run?

Comment: I close the application and reopen it, actually, to get the data it is necessary to press a button on the screen, on the first run and the first press, the data always returns null, but at other times it is still normal